# Matplotlib annotated heatmap - add commas for thousand separators

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, number-formatting

I am trying to add thousand comma separators in the annotated heatmap. For the image shown below, I want the values to have thousand comma separators like 5100 should look like 5,100 similarly 5892 should look like 5,892.

[image]

My code is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300)
im = ax.imshow(values_hmp)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(Months_hmp)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(Year_hmp)))
# ... and label them with the respective list entries
ax.set_xticklabels(Months_hmp)
ax.set_yticklabels(Year_hmp)

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")
for i in range(len(Year_hmp)):
    for j in range(len(Months_hmp)):
        text = ax.text(j, i, values_hmp[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", color="#000000")

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    text = ax.text(j, i, values_hmp[i, j],
                   ha="center", va="center", color="#000000")
```

to:

```
    text = ax.text(j, i, f"{values_hmp[i, j]:,}",
                   ha="center", va="center", color="#000000")
```